# typing.Generator extract ReturnType from Generator

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

taking this properly typed example from the official [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator):

```py
def echo_round() -> Generator[int, float, str]:
    sent = yield 0
    while sent >= 0:
        sent = yield round(sent)
    return 'Done'
```

How does one "extract" the ReturnType? Consider the following example:

```py
def use_generator() -> str:
    # Do generator stuff, keeping this a minimal example...
    next(echo_round())
    # Finally get the return value
    val = echo_round()
    # Do something else?
    return val
```

The mypy error message I receive for the last line:

```
Incompatible return value type (got "Generator[int, float, str]", expected "str")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `val` variable receives the generator object from `echo_round()`. The `val` value stays a generator type because the code does nothing with the value, and therefore is returned as `Generator[int, float, str]` type. This is causing an error because `use_generator()` expects to return `val` as `str` type.

Comment: Irrespective of the example, with your answer I realized that this is indeed the problem with my code. Solved and settled . Thanks for this impressive answer within seconds :) Best!

Comment: For context: I'm using the simpy framework, which heavily relies on yield and Generators for its internal workings. I ended up in a moment of confusion :)

Comment: If you say you are using `simpy` @ThomDietrich maybe also `typing.cast` can help. E.g. you have `s = simpy.Store(env)`, then you put and get: `s.put(1)`, `val: int = s.get().value`. Here mypy will complain. So you could `val: int = typing.cast(int, s.get().value)`. Or do you handle this in a better way?